# Code from Java to C#

Tags: java, c#, selenium

How can I rewrite the following code from Java to C#?

```
public List<IWebElement> findAll (By by)
{
    return driver.FindElements(by);
}
```

If I copy paste, i obtain the following error:

```
cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution is change method signature to:

```
public IList<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement> findAll (By by)
```

Second solution is call `.ToList()` extension method:

```
return driver.FindElements(by).ToList();
```

Comment: Mmmm...I suggest making it simply `IEnumerable<IWebElement>` and ensuring that the namespace `OpenQA.Selenium` is in the `using` block's. `ToList` is a little unnecessary and counterproductive (i.e don't call something into memory until you need to use it).